# Set default property to a variable while destucturing

Tags: javascript

I have a  variable id and remainingSettings. I filter id from settings object, then I use filtered remainingSettings object. How Can I set default value to id (id can absent and script will be broken)

```
const { id, ...remainingSettings } = settings
```

Comment: ```const { id="defaultId", ...remainingSettings } = settings||{};``` try this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `const {id = null, ...remainingSettings} =  settings;`

Comment: I also filter the id value from settings, so it doesn't work. Sorry for incorrect explanation

Comment: What do you want to achieve here?

Comment: I want to use remainingSettings without id, but id can absent in some situations and program will be broken

Comment: this will work or you can use if (id===undefined) id=null

Comment: yeah, thx. I've figired it out. we just need to add condition before desctructuring like if (settings?.id) { do descructuring }

Comment: that is es2020 feature and you need to have babel transpiler to use that. Available in latest version of react.

Comment: yeah, we use transpiler in our project

Comment: great it should work but it doesn't assign default value it just keeps the variable from throwing error. Check https://iolap.com/2019/09/27/whats-next-for-javascript-top-5-new-features-for-2020/

Comment: Actually I don't need default value for id. I'd like to filter it from settings. Before the condition if the value is absent, the program will be broken

Answer (score 3):

`const { id = 'defaultvalue', ...remainingSettings } = settings`